# Dictionary with 2 values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv, dictionary

That's my CSV file Test.csv:

```
AAA, 81, 82, *, *
BBB, 83, 84, *, *
CCC, -, 86, *, *
DDD, 87, 88, *, *
EEE, 89, 90, *, *
FFF, 99, -, -, *
GGG, 102, 108, -, *
```

Normally, I use this line to create a dictionary from a CSV file and check if a variable is in my dictionary:

```
var dictionary = File.ReadLines(@"Test.csv").Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToDictionary(data => data[0], data => data[1]);
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(variable.ToString()))
{
    var tmp = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == variable.ToString()).Value;
    Description.Add(tmp);
}
```

But now, there are two values (e.g. 81, 82) for each key (e.g. AAA).

Does anyone have a solution for me to check the variable against both values?

Comment: Using a dictionary is slightly odd here to start with, given that you're not looking up by the key. You've basically got a sequence of key/value pairs, not necessarily in the order you'd expect. Are there always exactly two values, or could there be more in the future?

Comment: Yes, there are always exactly two values. Not more in the future.

Comment: Dont use `var tmp = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == variable.ToString()).Value;` to check if a a dictionary contains a key. That is _very_ **inefficient** and also **buggy** (if `FirstOrDefault` returns `null`). Instead use `dictionary.TryGetValue`.

Comment: I take back the part of my comment about not looking up by key - you *are* doing so, but really inefficiently.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree that TryGetValue is indicated here, but it's also worth noting that inside the `if (dictionary.ContainsKey(variable.ToString()))` block we could just write `description.Add(dictionary[variable.ToString()]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I'm following your original code... how about this.. Changes your dictionary from a `<string, string>` dictionary to an `<string, IEnumerable<string>>` dictionary.  So a dictionary of collection of strings.  I changed your FirstOrDefault code... it made me scratch my head too much.

```
var dictionary = File.ReadLines(@"Test.csv").Select(line => line.Split(',')).ToDictionary(data => data[0], data => data.Skip(1).Take(data.Count - 3));
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(variable.ToString()))
{
    var tmp = dictionary[variable.ToString()]
    foreach(string str in tmp)
       Description.Add(str);
}
```

This will give you a dictionary from the CSV for any number of values, assuming you don't take the last two.

Comment: I get this value for key AAA: {[AAA, System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[System.String]]}

Comment: Correct. A value for AAA, as I tried to explain above will be a collection of strings.  That's the reason why there is a foreach to loop through the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just create a new class or struct to encapsulate the two values. You *could* use `Tuple<,>` instead, but personally I'd create a new type so that you can use friendlier property names. You might want to include *all* the data from the line there, in fact... then your CSV parsing code could become something like:

```
var dictionary = File.ReadLines("Test.csv")
                     .Select(Entry.FromCsv) // Static method in the Entry class
                     .ToDictionary(e => e.Name);

...

// Looking up by name
Entry entry;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out entry))
{
    // Now use entry, with all the relevant properties
}
```

Just the simple act of encapsulating all the data from one line of the CSV file is likely to make all kinds of code that works with it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a dictionary of dictionary and just to hide the dirty implementation details then lookup a Trictionary, several implementations over the web.